# Return doesn't seem to be awaiting javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

```
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)

const buildMap = async () => {
  let map = await readFile(process.argv[2], { encoding: 'utf-8' })
  console.log(map) // Returns the right result
  return map // Returns `Promise { <pending> }`
}

const game = buildMap()
console.log(game)
```

Why is it that in the code above, specifically

```
let map = await readFile(process.argv[2], { encoding: 'utf-8' })
console.log(map) // Returns the right result
return map // Returns Promise { <pending> }
```

that the return returns Promise pending, even though the line above it has the right result? And how could I change this so that it does?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the badly written question... (Writing well formulated SO questions is not one of my strong points)

Comment: Can you add this as an answer please

Comment: @CertainPerformance please do not answer questions in comments. Not taking the time to reply makes someone replying look like they copied your comment - as if they didn't know the answer to the question anyway!

Comment: @traktor53 Ok, I turned it into an answer. I noticed that others often answer tiny questions in comments, and when I post a real  answer (to trivial but non-typo questions) rather than a comment, it sometimes attracts downvotes.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for posting the answer. Some others are known for answering in comments but are too elderly to correct :-)  Attracting a downvote has its own criteria of risk - a downvote may suggest the answer could be imporved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` functions always return promises (even if their operations are completely synchronous). You have to call `.then` on the result of the call.

```
buildMap().then((game) => {
  // do stuff with game
  console.log(game);
});
```

Note that you can't just consume it with something like

```
const game = await buildMap();
```

because you can't `await` on the top level - you can only `await` inside of an async function.

Comment: oh, thanks, I missed the point on "top-level `await`". I've googled pretty article around this thing: https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/0b6f317657f5167663b493c722647221